# NotImplementedError when attempting to assign values to a new column of a groupby object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

The subtraction works and returns `Series` with the same index as the `groupby` object (months of the year i.e. 1-12). Creating a new column and assigning the values to the new column seems to cause the `NotImplementedError`.

I'm trying to subtract the 12 monthly values from the appropriate month in their original `dataframe` i.e. the value in at `1` (January) should be subtracted from every data point falling in January and so on.

```
test = df
grouped = test.groupby(test.index.month)
values_to_subtract = grouped['A'].median() - test['A'].median()
print values_to_subtract
grouped['new col'] = grouped['B'] - values_to_subtract
print grouped['new col']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-226-9bff427dc855> in <module>()
      3 values_to_subtract = grouped['A'].median() - test['A'].median()
      4 print values_to_subtract
----> 5 grouped['new col'] = grouped['B'] - values_to_subtract
      6 print grouped['new col']

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(left, right, name)
    503             if hasattr(lvalues, 'values'):
    504                 lvalues = lvalues.values
--> 505             return left._constructor(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
    506                                      index=left.index, name=left.name,
    507                                      dtype=dtype)

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    443         try:
    444             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y,
--> 445                                           raise_on_error=True, **eval_kwargs)
    446         except TypeError:
    447             if isinstance(y, (pa.Array, pd.Series)):

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expressions.pyc in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    210     if use_numexpr:
    211         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
--> 212                          **eval_kwargs)
    213     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
    214 

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expressions.pyc in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, raise_on_error, **eval_kwargs)
     63     if _TEST_MODE:
     64         _store_test_result(False)
---> 65     return op(a, b)
     66 
     67 

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in <lambda>(x, y)
     70         rmul=arith_method(operator.mul, names('rmul'), op('*'),
     71                           default_axis=default_axis, reversed=True),
---> 72         rsub=arith_method(lambda x, y: y - x, names('rsub'), op('-'),
     73                           default_axis=default_axis, reversed=True),
     74         rtruediv=arith_method(lambda x, y: operator.truediv(y, x),

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    487 
    488     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 489         raise NotImplementedError
    490 
    491     def _make_wrapper(self, name):

NotImplementedError: 

1    -3.40
2    -3.60
3    -5.30
4     0.15
5     1.80
6    -0.80
7     2.15
8     6.70
9     3.90
10    1.45
11   -0.75
12   -2.70
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to be using a [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) here:

```
test['A'] - grouped['A'].transform("median")
```

---

This is some strange code...

```
grouped = test.groupby(test.index.month)
values_to_subtract = grouped['A'].median() - test['A'].median()
```

Now, `values_to_subtract` is a Series (assuming there is only one 'A' column, whilst `grouped['B']` is a SeriesGrouby object... it doesn't make sense to subtract them!

```
grouped['B'] - values_to_subtract
```

Also, you can't assign a column to a DataFrameGroupby object, so even if the above were a Series:

```
grouped['new col'] = _
TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: You were right, using the `.transform`: `values_to_subtract = test['A'].median() - grouped['A'].transform('median')`
Allowed me to create a series which I could use when assigning a new column.